# How to change the vibility of a button in dashcode programmatically?

Tags: javascript, button, web-applications, dashcode

i'm using dashcode for a webapp and in order to add a + button in the browser bar to a specific view i need to hide and unhide that + button.
The problem is i really don't know how to do this.
I tried to write on the screen all the button's properties and in fact there is a visible parameter but when i display the value it shows "null" knowing that the button is visible...

So anyone has got an idea ?
Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put the button in a div

```
<div id="peekaboo">button</div>
```

then in the css set the visibility of peekaboo to the initial state visible or hidden
then write a JavaScript function which will switch the css style state to visible or hidden as required.

Sorry i am away from my base computer so cannot access the code samples. can post better code tonight if you still need it

Answer (score 1):

you can do this in two ways.

1)use display and toggle it (block/none)
2)use visibility and toggle it (visible/hidden)

If you want to know the difference between display and visibility, look at [display docs](http://wiw.org/~frb/css-docs/display/display.html)